# Action bar on pre-honey comb devices by using Android support-v4 library

Tags: android

I want to design Action bar UI on pre-honeycomb devices. After my Google i got ActionBarSherlock library. Can i design without using this ActionbarSherlock library. is it possible to design Action bar on pre-honey comb devices by using Android support-v4 library itself?

Basically i trying to design without using third party libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. Action bar was not included in the support-v4 library. To use action bar on pre-honeycomb devices, you can either use SherlockActionBar, or you can try to develop something to simulate this bar. Something like making a custom view and include this view in all your layout xml files. However, this would be way too much effort to do so. SherlockActionBar is easy to use for me, afterall.